# Select first entry using reference id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to find a solution for my problem. Let's assume I have a table with 3 columns:

`ID   |   contract_number   |   ref_contract_number
 1    |          1          |            1 
 2    |          2          |            1
 3    |          3          |            1
 4    |          4          |            1
 5    |          5          |            4
 6    |          6          |            5`

and so on...

How can I get the first ID using the ref_contract_number ? So If I have ref_contract_number = 5 or 4, I want to get the row with ID 1 because the that's the first entry with connection between contract_number and ref_contract_number. There is no telling how deep the connection goes, the result must be the first entry (the last connection) from a ref_contract_number. Please help!

My select statement should look like:

```
Select........................
where ref_contract_number = 5
```

and my result would be

`ID   |   contract_number   |   ref_contract_number
 1    |          1          |            1`

The logic would be : Each entry has a contract number and a reference contract number. If it's the first contract, then they would be the same. But from a contract can also come a new entry with a new number, but a reference to the previous contract. So ID 2 - 4 is a new entry for the previous contract with number 1. ID 5 is a contract for previous contract number 4 and ID 6 is a new entry for the previous contract with number 5. So I need to select the very first contract for ref_number 5. 
The connection would be :

1. ref_contract = 5 --> contract = 5
2. contract 5 has ref contract 4 --> contract = 4
3. contract 4 has ref contract 1 --> contract = 1
4. contract 1 has no other ref contract then itself --> result

Comment: can you please explain your logic more details

Comment: Post your expected result too!

Comment: You need the recursive CTE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @vignesh : I added the logic to the question.

Comment: @Serg : I tried also CTE query (WITH.......Select......). I just can't seem to get the result I want.

Comment: @Alex, see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using recursive cte

```
with 
  -- sample data
  mytable as(
  select *
  from (
     values
        (1, 1, 1) 
       ,(2, 2, 1)
       ,(3, 3, 1)
       ,(4, 4, 1)
       ,(5, 5, 4)
       ,(6, 6, 5)         
     ) t(ID, contract_number, ref_contract_number)
),
rcte as(
  select ID, contract_number, ref_contract_number, 1 level
  from mytable
  where ref_contract_number = 5
  union all
  select p.ID, p.contract_number, p.ref_contract_number, level+1
  from rcte 
  join mytable p  on p.contract_number = rcte.ref_contract_number and p.contract_number != p.ref_contract_number
)
select * 
from  mytable
where contract_number = (select top(1) with ties ref_contract_number top_contract
                         from rcte 
                         order by row_number() over(order by level desc))
```

To simplify the query usage wrap it into an inline TVF 
[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b6ea8733fe2ff397d6bd273704da0cb3)

Comment: Thank you very much! I only know basic SQLs so I can't do any recursive CTE like your statement :(